# Pause execution until the child dialog is closed

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog

I am trying to open a `JDialog` from `JFrame`. I want to pause the execution until the child dialog is being closed, but the main frame is being executed continuously without any pause. I am using the following code.

What is alternate solution?

```
Class NewFrame extends JFrame

 NewFrame()

  try 
    {
       NewDialog frm = new NewDialog();
       frm.show();

       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"yes");
     }
  catch(Exception ex)
   {
   ex.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

In the above program I want a message should be displayed when the dialog box should be closed.

Comment: Make sure that NewDialog is extend from JDialog and is set to modal (setModal(true)). You might like to take a look at [How to use Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Comment: ya it worked thanks a lot . can it work with extending JFrame also

Comment: No - Only dialogs have the concept of modal

Comment: @MadProgrammer, please make your comment an answer, so it can be accepted and we get this question out of the “unanswered” queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that `NewDialog` is extend from `JDialog` and is set to modal (`setModal(true)`). You might like to take a look at [How to use Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)