# Java Modal Dialog Won't Block Code Execution

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

Basically.. I made a JDialog using swing. And now I want it to return a value to the JFrame that called it. Problem is, whenever I call the constructor for the JDialog, it won't block the thread even though I've set `setModal(true)`. Am I missing something obvious here?

```
private final JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
private File chosenFile = null;
private JList list;
private File[] files;

public File getInformation()
{
    return chosenFile;      
}

/**
 * Create the dialog.
 */
public PatientPicker(JFrame parent)
{
    super(parent);
    setModal(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(parent);

    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 396);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    contentPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    getContentPane().add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    files = new File(ClientInfo.GetAppData() + "/patients").listFiles(new TextFileFilter());

    {
        JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
        buttonPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
        getContentPane().add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        {
            JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");
            okButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                    if(files.length != 0)
                        chosenFile = files[list.getSelectedIndex()];
                    dispose();
                }
            });
            okButton.setActionCommand("OK");
            buttonPane.add(okButton);
            getRootPane().setDefaultButton(okButton);
        }
        {
            JButton cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");
            cancelButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                    dispose();
                }
            });
            cancelButton.setActionCommand("Cancel");
            buttonPane.add(cancelButton);
        }
    }
}
```

And then here is how I create it:

```
PatientPicker patientPicker = new PatientPicker(frmReportGenerator);
File dataFile = patientPicker.getInformation();
```

Comment: Modal is about blocking user interaction with other components, not other threads.

Comment: @chrylis According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292071/pause-execution-until-the-child-dialog-is-closed) that's not necessarily true...

Comment: The link you've supplied is for code running on the event thread. So yes, all that @chrylis states **is** necessarily true.

Comment: Okay, so I suppose my question would be: How do I get the behaviour I want? All I need is to return a value from a JDialog

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You state:

> Problem is, whenever I call the constructor for the JDialog, it won't block the thread even though I've set setModal(true). Am I missing something obvious here?

The constructor will never block the event thread. Modality means that the event thread is blocked only when you call setVisible (true) on your modal dialog (as per the api).

---

Unrelated problem: you should not use MouseListeners on JButtons but rather ActionListeners. Otherwise you will run into major problems now, such as when you press the file via the space bar, and while it does depress, nothing happens, and in later code, such as say when you make the button disabled, and yet it is still functioning, even though it looks disabled.

---

Now if you are still having problems, then you may wish to post more code, a [minimal code example program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which would allow us to understand and experience your problem.

---

**Edit**
You state:

> Yes. The user chooses a file in the JDialog and I want it to return to the JFrame that called it.

Why not just use a JFileChooser modal dialog?

---

**Edit 2**
An example using a JOptionPane:

```
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SwingFoo extends JPanel {
   private JTextField fileField = new JTextField(20);
   private JButton showDialog = new JButton(new ShowDialogAction("Show Dialog",
         KeyEvent.VK_D, this));

   public SwingFoo() {
      fileField.setEditable(false);
      fileField.setFocusable(false);
      add(new JLabel("File Selected:"));
      add(fileField);
      add(showDialog);
   }

   public void setFileFieldText(String text) {
      fileField.setText(text);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      SwingFoo mainPanel = new SwingFoo();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("SwingFoo");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class ShowDialogAction extends AbstractAction {
   private SwingFoo swingFoo;

   public ShowDialogAction(String name, int mnemonic, SwingFoo swingFoo) {
      super(name);
      putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
      this.swingFoo = swingFoo;
   }

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      PatientPicker patientPicker = new PatientPicker();
      int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(swingFoo, patientPicker,
            "Select Something", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
      if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
         swingFoo.setFileFieldText(patientPicker.getSelectedItem());
      }
      patientPicker.setVisible(true);
   }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class PatientPicker extends JPanel {
   private static final String[] ITEMS = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",
         "Thursday", "Friday", "Sunday", "Fubar", "Snafu", "DILLIGAF", "BOHICA"};
   private JList<String> selectionList = new JList<>(ITEMS);

   public PatientPicker() {
      add(new JScrollPane(selectionList));
      selectionList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
   }

   public String getSelectedItem() {
      return selectionList.getSelectedValue();
   }

}
```

Comment: @JABFreeware: A dialog is built to block when it is visible.

Comment: @JABFreeware: if the constructor blocked, you wouldn't be able to construct your object, set up your property change listeners, and then make it visible. I cannot complain with the way it is set up.

Comment: Alright.. that all makes sense. So how would I get the behaviour I'm looking for? All I'm trying to do is return a value from my JDialog and I guess I implemented the solutions online incorrectly...

Comment: @CCInc: what exactly are you trying to return? A File?

Comment: Yes. The user chooses a file in the JDialog and I want it to return to the JFrame that called it. I was going for something like [this](http://crypt-sdk.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-return-value-from-jdialog-in.html)

Comment: @CCInc: why not just use a JFileChooser modal dialog?

Comment: My chooser requires a special functionality that the JFileChooser can't preform.

Comment: @CCInc: what functionality is that?

Comment: Well, I suppose the JFileChooser could do it via a filter but it doesn't have a nice interface.. I'm extracting the core filenames from a directory and displaying them in a JList

Comment: Should it really be all that complicated? In other languages it's not that difficult to simply return a value from a JDialog

Comment: @CCInc: Not suppose, it **does** do filtering, else it would not be of much use.

Comment: @CCInc: it's not hard to do in Java, but your code doesn't show us where your failings are, other than we don't see anywhere that you call `setVisible(true)` on your dialog, and the unrelated issue of your JButtons being given MouseListeners.

Comment: @CCInc: see edit for a JOptionPane example. This little guys make for nice quick and easy dialogs, and know that they can accept complex GUI's inside of them.

Comment: @CCInc have a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24291619/2587435) using an accessory for a JFileChooser. Maybe it might be of interest to you.

Comment: @CCInc: and be sure to up-vote peeskillet's wonderful example while you're at it!

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is have a way to send a notification to your main window once the user has completed interacting with the dialog assuming they clicked the ok button.
You can do this by creating an anonymous class and passing that along in the constructor of your Dialog.

let's assume that you open the dialog with a button called openDialogBtn from the main window:

```
openDialogBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            new PatientPicker(this, new FileSelectionNotifier() {
                public void okButtonPressed(File chosenFile) {

                    // do whatever you need to do with the file (assign to a member variable
                    // or call another thread to do some kind of processing

                }
            });
```

In your dialog window you would need to have something like this:

```
okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


            dispose();
            // notify that the ok button was pressed
            fileSelectionNotifier.okButtonPressed(chosenFile); 
        }
}
```